# WP_Query order by meta returns 0 results

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to order posts by a meta value which is a date field but I keep getting 0 results. I've tested that there is data by querying without the meta order by.

```
$args = array(
                'post_type'  => 'lp-reviews',
                'p'          => $review_id,
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'meta_key' => 'job_completion_date',
                'meta_type' => 'date',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => 'DESC'
            );
```

Am I missing anything obvious?

Comment: meta value is "10/10/2018"

Comment: Add post_per_page => -1 property and check the result once more.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be that the query array was indeed correct but the way the data had been stored was incorrect. I was trying to search data which was a serialized object which obviously would never work.